# Requesting "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission from the user. Android, JAVA

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to find out how to request "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission from the user.

My manifest file has the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

Here is my code to request permissions:

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
        android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS,
};

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
```

And here's a callback function for requesting permissions:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < permissions.length; i++) {
        Log.w(Common.LOG_KEY, "permissions[i]: " + permissions[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
        Log.w(Common.LOG_KEY, "grantResults[i]: " + grantResults[i]);
    }
    if (hasRequiredPermissions(grantResults)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("You have not accepted all of the permissions");
    }
}
```

And the callback function prints the following:

```
2021-02-20 21:01:39.493 7112-7112/com.example.calculator3 W/myApp: permissions[i]: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
2021-02-20 21:01:39.493 7112-7112/com.example.calculator3 W/myApp: permissions[i]: android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
2021-02-20 21:01:39.493 7112-7112/com.example.calculator3 W/myApp: permissions[i]: android.permission.VIBRATE
2021-02-20 21:01:39.493 7112-7112/com.example.calculator3 W/myApp: grantResults[i]: 0
2021-02-20 21:01:39.493 7112-7112/com.example.calculator3 W/myApp: grantResults[i]: -1
2021-02-20 21:01:39.493 7112-7112/com.example.calculator3 W/myApp: grantResults[i]: 0
```

How come I wasn't granted "android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" permission? And how would I properly get granted this permission?

Comment: `How come I wasn't granted "android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" permission? ` Your post has a strange subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun requestStoragePermission(){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).toString())){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Need permission to add background image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
    }
```

I used this for requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.